# Samsung Galaxy A70 stuck in boot loop

Tags: updates, recovery-mode, boot-loop

I have a Samsung Galaxy A70 (A705FN) which worked fine until i decided to update to Android 10. I downloaded the update and everything was fine until the phone restarted and got stuck in a boot loop. I did some research and everyone suggested that Wipe Cache would do the trick.

But the problem is i can't access recovery menu. When hold down power and volume up buttons a blue screen pops up and says Installing Updates ... and goes 0 to 100% and then restarts and i'm stuck in the loop again. No matter how many times it doesn't do anything.

I tried to use third party recovery modes like TWRP but i did not enable usb debbuging or unlocked bootloader so this is not an option for me.

So ... how do i fix this? Thanks

Comment: flash empty cache partition from ODIN